# What are the original movie titles spoofed in Unbreakable Kimmy?

Tags: reference, unbreakable-kimmy-schmidt

In Unbreakable Kimmy Season 3 episode 10 Kimmy pulls off a heist.

Titus goes on a date and they leave a cinema with the following spoof titles:

- Daddy’s Boy (remastered!)
- My Dinner Without Andre
- Jiro Dreams of Tushi
- A Fistful of Dollhairs

So the last 3 are [My Dinner with Andre](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082783/),
 [Jiro: Dreams of Sushi](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1772925/), and [Fistful of Dollars](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058461/) but is the first one [Daddy's Boy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4868300/)? This is a fairly recent movie and there isn't much of a title change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a title parody, but it seems that *Daddy's Boy* is just a reference to Logan Beekman, made in the style of a 30's musical. According to Jeff Richmond (who directed the episode) in an interview to [TVGuide.com](http://www.tvguide.com/news/unbreakable-kimmy-schmidt-songs-jeff-richmond/):

> The concept of a daddy's boy came up in the writing process," he says. "I can't remember which writer it was, but that is also such a funny thing for Logan [Adam Campbell] to call himself a daddy's boy, and what did that imply? We just kept going with it to see how far we could take it.

Comment: That's pretty interesting, I flagged that particular title because the other titles are clearly parodies, whilst that IMDB linked title is already a film about homosexuals so it seemed to be coincidental and nothing else came up on my searches. Thanks for this. Actually that link seems to be the best explanation as it explains the history of the Daddy's Boy concept and how they played around with it and probably added it as a continuation of this joke

Comment: Even if it is a parody of a specific movie, it's not the movie "Daddy's Boy" referenced in the question.  The fictional movie "Daddy's Boy" was first referenced in Season 1 of Kimmy Schmidt, which came out in 2015;  the movie linked in the original question came out in 2016.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert indeed I originally thought that all the movie titles were parodies of existing movies and IMDB only turned up that movie, I wasn't aware of the original reference to Season 1 and that this is the more likely reference